# Disable future date after date range selection in bootstrap datepicker calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#from").datepicker({maxDate:"+6D"});
    $("#to").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            var toDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+6)
            $("#from").datepicker("setDate", toDate);
       }
    });
});
```

I want to disable all the dates after the range selection of the date.
E.G.- I will select the start date 1 feb so To date will fill automatic 7 feb.I want after 7 feb all dates will be disable. This all functionality want to bootstrap calender not in jquery calendar.

Comment: What particular plugin are you using for calendar? Cos there are lot of bootstrap calendars plugin available..

Comment: Could you please provide link to the plugin?

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/                                          I am using this calendar.

Comment: What should be the `startDate` for `from`?

Comment: **[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/y9owk12y/)** based on your inputs, on how you can achieve it..

Comment: How can I date fill automatic in set second tab according to automatic means +6  days date fill also?

Comment: You mean automatically you want to select 6th day in **to datepicker** once date is selected in **from datepicker**?

Comment: Yes I need this also...Remain is working Good..Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do. Write `changeDate` event for `#from - datepicker` and use options like `setStartDate`, `setEndDate` and `setDate` by adding +6 days to selected from date.

```
$("#from").datepicker({
  startDate: new Date() 
}).on('changeDate',function(e){
    var newDate=new Date();//get today's date instance
    newDate.setDate(e.date.getDate()+6); //add selected from date + 6 to today's date
    $("#to").datepicker('setDate',newDate); //setDate of to
    $("#to").datepicker('setEndDate',newDate);//setEndDate of to
    $("#to").datepicker('setStartDate',e.date);//setStartDate of to
});
$("#to").datepicker();
```

**[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/y9owk12y/2/)**